# Problem installing Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation

My screen turns black after choose "Try Ubuntu without installing" i have a lenovo ideapad y400, also do the same in a friend laptop and work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- At install screen press <kbd>F6</kbd> and select `nomodeset` and install Ubuntu as usual.
- On first boot after install, press e on getting the GRUB bootloader.
- Using arrow keys navigate to and delete `quiet` and `splash` and type the word `nomodeset` in their place
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot
- You should now be able to login to your Ubuntu as usual.