# Ubuntu blackscreen while installation

Tags: installation, drivers, kernel

I am trying to install ubuntu for hours. I have an Asus UX32VD. I followed [these](http://webent.altervista.org/2012/09/16/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-12-04-or-newer-on-the-zenbook-ux32vd/) [guides](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime#A.28Not_so.29_Experimental_Fn_keys_workaround).

But no matter what I always get a black screen. I googled this problem but the solution with `nomodeset` doesn't work for me.
( [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076) and [Problem installing Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260305/problem-installing-ubuntu-12-10) )

I replaced splash with nomodeset while pressing e on "try ubuntu without installing". Then I pressed F10.

I also tried this [ubuntu install black screen - nomodeset not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225207/ubuntu-install-black-screen-nomodeset-not-working) But it seems we have exactly the same issue

I downloaded 12.04 and 12.10 64bit. I currently have installed Fedora on a GPT partiton. I "broke" it because I installed nvidia drivers and now it didn't boot to a gui anymore. I thought I give ubuntu a try.

I mounted my usb stick with several different tools. unetbootin and win32diskmanager.

Any other ideas that I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by myself. If you have an Asus you have to disable "Secure boot control". I read somewhere that it may causes some troubles but it is the only solution that works for me.